# Using reducer (combineReducers) in React Redux

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, redux-reducers

I am trying to use combineReducers in React redux but i keep receiving this error in the console.

> "reducer" is a required argument, and must be a function or an object
> of functions that can be passed to combineReducers

the store.js

```
import { configureStore } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";
import { combineReducers } from "redux";

const reducer = combineReducers({});

const initialState = {};

const store = configureStore(reducer, initialState);

export default store;
```

Comment: is it on purpose that you transmit an empty object to `combineReducers`?

Comment: @Stephane it is, I haven't built any actual reducer yet i am just setting up

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like mentioned on the [documentation](https://redux.js.org/api/combinereducers), you must transmit an object with several method as properties to `combinereducers`. These methods are the reducers.

To make it simple, what you transmit to `combineReducers` must be an object only with methods that have the signature that is described [here](https://redux.js.org/understanding/thinking-in-redux/glossary#reducer)